# pandas update/replace from different data frame

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes: df1 and df2. df1 has columns ['UserId', 'company', 'deg'] and has 100 observations. df2 has columns ['UserId', 'deg'] and has 10 observations. The indices in df1 and df2 match perfectly - with the 'userId'.

I want to update df1 with those in df2. The 'UserId' columns in df2 is a subset of 'UserId' columns in df1....so, there is nothing to append. Just based on 'userId' (and/or plain index).

df1

```
,'UserId','Company','deg'
6,'john21','ibm','bs'
12,'mary33','cisco','ms'
16,'smith11','intel','none'
20,'lucy55','intel','bs'
33,'tanya32','fb','ms'
39,'ssri44','google','none'
45,'har43','CDs','none'
```

df2

```
,'UserId','deg'
16,'smith11','BS'
39,'ssri44','MS'
45,'har43','MS'
```

Now, I want to use the information in df2 to update df1. As you see, the index values and userIds match perfectly with those in df1.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `None` to `NaN` and then use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for updating `None` values in `df1` by `df2`:

```
df1.replace({"'none'": np.nan}, inplace=True)
#or omit '', for me works uncomment version
#df1.replace({"none": np.nan}, inplace=True)

print df1.fillna(df2)

     'UserId' 'Company' 'deg'
6    'john21'     'ibm'  'bs'
12   'mary33'   'cisco'  'ms'
16  'smith11'   'intel'  'BS'
20   'lucy55'   'intel'  'bs'
33  'tanya32'      'fb'  'ms'
39   'ssri44'  'google'  'MS'
45    'har43'     'CDs'  'MS'
```

Another solution with [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df1.replace({"'none'": np.nan}, inplace=True)

df1.update(df2)
print df1
     'UserId' 'Company' 'deg'
6    'john21'     'ibm'  'bs'
12   'mary33'   'cisco'  'ms'
16  'smith11'   'intel'  'BS'
20   'lucy55'   'intel'  'bs'
33  'tanya32'      'fb'  'ms'
39   'ssri44'  'google'  'MS'
45    'har43'     'CDs'  'MS'
```

If you want update `df2` by `df1` use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print pd.merge(df2,df1,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='left', on=["'UserId'","'deg'"])
     'UserId' 'deg' 'Company'
16  'smith11'  'BS'   'intel'
39   'ssri44'  'MS'  'google'
45    'har43'  'MS'     'CDs'
```